# How to access an instantiated GameObject from another function in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, void

I just want to use the instantiated GameObject in another function but it always says
The name 'newObject' does not exist in the current context

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Deletenow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public GameObject myObject;
    public Vector2 thisVector;

    void Start()
    {
        thisFunction();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        thisVector = newObject.transform.position;
    }

    public void thisFunction()
    {
        GameObject newObject = Instantiate(myObject, Player.transform.position, Player.rotation);
    }

}
```

I couldn't find any source that could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to make the variable global or return it, whenever you call the function. As an example, look at thisFunction() and thatFunction()

```
public class Deletenow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public GameObject myObject;
    public GameObject newObject;
    public Vector2 thisVector;
    public Vector2 thatVector;

void Start()
{
    thisFunction();
}

void Update()
{
    thisVector = newObject.transform.position;
    thatVector = thatFunction().transform.position;
}

// init object - global variable
public void thisFunction()
{
    newObject = Instantiate(myObject, Player.transform.position, Player.rotation);
}

// init object - returns object
public GameObject thatFunction() {
    GameObject objectToReturn = Instantiate(myObject, Player.transform.position, Player.rotation);
    return objectToReturn;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that newObject is defined in the scope of the function. Define it below the class declaration, so that it will persist. Then remove the GameObject part of

`newObject=Instantiate(myObject,Player.transform.position,Player.rotation);`

The class will look like `public class DeleteNow : MonoBehaviour  { GameObject newObject;… }`

Answer (score 0):

To complete Xa4 answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74620220/20467840

> You either need to make the variable global or return it, whenever you call the function. As an example, look at thisFunction() and thatFunction()

There is a third way to access an instancied object, using reference:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Deletenow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Player;
    public GameObject myObject;
    public Vector2 thisVector;

    void Start()
    {
        thisFunction(out myObject);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        thisVector = myObject.transform.position;
    }

    public void thisFunction(out GameObject newObject)
    {
        newObject = Instantiate(myObject, Player.transform.position, Player.rotation);
    }

}
```

Can be very usefull if you need to keep your return value for other data, like a boolean.